# border alignment issue while using Twitter bootstrap responsive css

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I found this post on [Bootstrap Tutorial for Blog Design](http://www.9lessons.info/2012/03/bootstrap-tutorial-for-blog-design.html).
I am planning to use it for one of my project for the responsive layout that it provides. 
I have found an issue in the page hosted for [demo](http://demos.9lessons.info/bootstrap/index.html).
have attached a screenshot [image: Screenshot]
The first post in the page "Facebook Timeline Design using JQuery and CSS" is falling outside the border of the background [Have marked it in blue].[not the expected result]
The rest of the posts in the page falls inside the border which is the expected behaviour[have marked it in green].
Is there any way I can fix the issue of the first post falling outside the background border. I have tested this in IE,firefox and chrome with the same results.
have created a jsbin page [here](http://jsbin.com/anuvej/2/edit)

Comment: Please edit your title, it's undescriptive of the problem you have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get it resolved by using jquery selector

```
$('.row > [class*="span"]:first-child').css({"padding-left":"20px"});
```

Answer (score 1):

In the css files its stated that the first span-element to have no margin on the left.

bootstrap-responsive.css on line 232:

```
.row-fluid [class*="span"]:first-child { 
    margin-left: 0px;
}
```

bootstrap.css on line 419:

```
.row-fluid [class*="span"]:first-child { 
    margin-left: 0px;
}
```

Remove or comment these out.

Answer (score 0):

Add this stylesheet (*prefered at the bottom*)

```
.row > [class*="span"]:first-child {
    padding-left: 20px;
}
```

If you want you can add this jQuery

```
$('.row > [class*="span"]:first-child').css('padding-left','20px');
```

Comment: try running the jquery at your IE Dev toolbar you'll see it works